# What is wrong with my method to see if a value is in a 2D array in O(n) time?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, big-o

I'm trying to write a method that takes a 2D array(arranged so that the elements in every row are in increasing order from left to right, and the elements in every column are in increasing order from top to bottom) and an int, and sees if the int is in the 2D array. I wanted to use nested loops, but that would make it go in O(N^2) time. I'm therefore trying to make conditionals that make it so it tests if the int is smaller than the first in one of the sub arrays and bigger than the last, and if so, goes onto the next subarray. Here's what I have:

```
 static boolean has(int number, int[][] a) {
    int q = 0;
    boolean c = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < a[q].length-1; i++){
      if ((number < a[i][q]) || (number > a[a[j].length-1][i])){
        q++;
      }
      else if (number == a[i][q]){
        c = true;
        break;
      }
      else c = false;
    }
    return c;
  }
```

could use some help. This method compiles but gives me outOfBounds Thanks!

Comment: If you're getting an exception, post the stack trace.

Comment: where can I find that?

Comment: Right underneath "outOfBounds"

Comment: t HasIt.has(HasIt.java:10)
 at HasIt.main(HasIt.java:30)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

Comment: which line is 10?

Comment: the "if" statement

Comment: I think the best solution is O(n+m).

Comment: it just needs to not be any run time greater than O(n), meaning not O(n^2, log, 2^n, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution runs in O(n+m):

```
static boolean has(int number, int[][] a) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = a[0].length - 1;
    while (row < a.length && col >= 0) {
        int n = a[row][col];
        if (n < number) {
            row++;
        } else if (n > number) {
            col--;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in O(log(n) + log(m)) first find the row that contain the integer you're looking for using binary search (since columns are sorted), then find the exact position of the integer in that row, by performing another binary search (since rows are sorted).